# How to add sound in the beginning of android app?

Tags: audio, addition

It shows error when i use media player during runtime when i use this code :-
this is the code:-`MediaPlayer mp3=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ShootToThrill);
        mp3.start();`

Here are the errors :-
C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\Quiz\app\src\main\res\raw\ShootToThrill.mp3
Error:Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\Quiz\app\src\main\res\raw\ShootToThrill.mp3: Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rename your file, for example : shoot_to_thrill.mp3